# Java Do While statement logic error

Tags: java

I need to make a do-while statement to replace an if statement that tests an inputted interest rate. It must be >=0 and less than 1.0. If the interest rate is >=0, it will continue to ask for the interest rate until a valid number is entered. Then, if that valid number is greater than 1.0, it will take that rate and divide it by 100.0 because they must be decimal values less than 1.0.

```
 ...    

      do {
         System.out.println("Please enter the interest rate on your loan, must be >= 0:");
         interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
      }  while (interestRate < 0.0);
      do {
         interestRate = (interestRate/100.0);
         System.out.println("Interest rates must be entered as decimal values less than" +
         " 1.0. Interest rate will be saved as " + interestRate);
      }  while (interestRate > 1.0);

...
```

For a reason I cannot figure out, no matter what input is entered, the interest rate is being divided by 100.0 while it should only be doing it if the number entered is greater than 1.0.

Comment: it needs to be a completely composed of do whiles, it originally was an if statement

Comment: @nukacola7 you should have specified that requirements in your original question ...

Comment: "I need to make a do-while statement to replace an if statement" my very first sentence

Comment: thank you everyone for the suggestions, but im still having a problem with it outputting the second do-while even if the condition is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `do` loop is always executed at least once. This really isn't a place for a loop (Though a `while` loop would work). Your best bet is an `if` statement.

However... if you must use a `do` loop ...

adding `interestRate*=100.0;` between the loops should fix your problem.

This way if the interest rate is originally less than one everything will work great. If it is originally greater than 1 it will be divided by 100 twice, so again everything goes according to plan.

This might be a little messy, but I think it will solve all the problems.

```
  do {
     System.out.println("Please enter the interest rate on your loan, must be >= 0:");
     interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
  }  while (interestRate < 0.0);
  interestRate*=100.0;
  String str = "";
  do {
     interestRate = (interestRate/100.0);
     System.out.print(str);
     str="Interest rates must be entered as decimal values less than" +
     " 1.0. Interest rate will be saved as " + interestRate/100.0 + "\n";
  }  while (interestRate > 1.0);
```

Comment: it originally was an if statement, and i need to rewrite it as a do-while

Comment: @nukacola7 Edited the answer now that i fully understand the question.

Comment: thank you, that fixed my problem with it dividing my number by 100.0, but im still trying to figure out how to not have it output "Interest rates must be entered as decimal values less than..." if the interest rate is less than 1.0

Comment: @nukacola7 This should do it, the String is always printed but for the first iteration its completely empty, so there is only console output upon the second iteration.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it is not a while loop, is a do while and the statement is ever executed the first time no matter whether the condition is satisfied or not ...

Read about [do while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop in the documentation, if you want to achieve what you are asking for use a while instead .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean tryAgain = true;
do {
  System.out.println("Please enter the interest rate on your loan: ");
  interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
  if (interestRate >= 0.0 && interestRate < 1.0f){
    System.out.println("Error, Interest rate is improperly formatted!\n");
  } else {
    /* Do calculations Here */
    tryAgain = false
  }
} while (tryAgain);
```

You can also write it with just a while statement:

```
boolean tryAgain = true;
while (tryAgain){
  System.out.println("Please enter the interest rate on your loan: ");
  interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
  if (interestRate >= 0.0 && interestRate < 1.0f){
    System.out.println("Error, Interest rate is improperly formatted!\n");
  } else {
    /* Do calculations Here */
    tryAgain = false
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just read the only do while statements comment...

The problem with "do while" loop is that it makes it impossible to catch errors, because everything executes at least once in the "do while" block. So no matter how hard you tired, your error catching code will always run if all you used was "do while".

This is also *VERY* hard to do with just "while" statements, because if you are not careful, your program will get stuck in an infinite loop.

**EDIT 2:**

After a contemplative cup of lemonade, I think I have a solution...

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter the interest rate on your loan, must be >= 0:");
    interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();
}  while (interestRate < 0.0 && interestRate > 1.0);
/* Calculations and output follow. */
```

This will cause the input to loop until a correct value is input.

The problem with "if it is greater than one divide by 100 to get the percentage", is the if. You want to break off a logic branch, but without the use of the if statement it is not possible (to my knowledge). So you can only have one where the user inputs a decimal, or another where the user enters a number 0 to 100. Sadly, this may be one of the cases where you can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: I added an edit to hopefuly resolve your problems... I must say @nukacola7 it has been quite some time since I have used the do while loops. :)